# bidirectional data transfer between access and excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have one access database and it is linked to an excel sheet, Is it possible to update the excel and the access both bidirectionally.

such that, when a record is updated in access, it reflects in excel, and visa versa when the same record is again updated in excel it reflects in access.

Comment: How you excel is connected to access?

Comment: Microsoft query, I don't know if it is the perfect way to do it..I am open to trying other ways

Answer (score 0):

That could be done in Access up to an including version 97 before its last update. Then writing was blocked due to a patent dispute.

These days, a linked Excel worksheet or Named Range is read-only from Access, thus writing must be done via automation (open Excel from Access) or by exporting to the Excel file.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-data-from-excel-to-access-90c35a40-bcc3-46d9-aa7f-4106f78850b4

Is this process explained here just one way data transfer?

Comment: Yes. It is a general note on the topic "misuse of Excel as a database", where Access may be the better alternative, thus data could be permanently moved to Access. That is different from your case where you wish to maintain an Excel workbook from Access. You may study this video by my fellow MVP, _Anders Ebro_: [Automating Excel From Access](https://youtu.be/EUvoSDk-dvs).